# ADB shows unknown device

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, adb, linux

I've been developing in several Android devices since now but this one has me totally puzzled. ADB in Windows detects the device just fine, but I cannot make ADB recognize this device in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04).

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
????????????    device
```

1. Device is in USB debugging mode.
2. `lsusb` shows it as `Bus 003 Device 005: ID 18d1:0003 Google Inc.`
3. `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file has the following line: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"`
4. `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` has `0x18d1` in a line by itself

What I've attempted so far:

1. Restart ADB server - no luck
2. Start ADB server as root - no luck
3. Add this line `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="0003", MODE="0666", GROUP="adbusers"` to `51-android.rules` and add myself to `adbusers` group. Restart `udev` and ADB - no luck

Any hint welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: Strange. [This HowTo](http://www.hipatic.com/2012/08/chinese-android-debugging-how-to-use.html) seems to use exactly the same device for Eclipse on Ubuntu without any trouble. What device is it? According to the linked post, some Chinese no-name tablet? // You might also check [this wiki](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android_ADB_Setup), which also mentions the same vendorID.

Comment: @Izzy yes, it's a Chinese device, a prototype. I worked this out trying different USB ports until it ultimately worked... Strange...

Comment: So you got it solved? Don't hesitate to answer your own question then, even if the answer seems trivial (most solutions do *when you've got them*, but only few do so in advance :) I had a case driving me crazy until I noticed I forgot to turn *USB Debugging* on #D

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why it won't let me answer...

Comment: But you did answer :) So it was simply plugging the cable into a different hole? Too easy to think of, that almost matches my *USB Debugging* thingy :)

Comment: Yup, looks like I was logged out for no reason. And yeah, it was as simple as plugging it in another USB port... although it just makes no sense xD

Comment: OK. So just remember to accept your solution in 2 days :)

Comment: Yes Izzy, don't worry, I know how SE works, I'm usual in SO ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing USB port made ADB recognize the Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Kill adb server using using

> sudo

and start it again with sudo.

If you start adb server with sudo in linux it will detect.

Comment: Thanks, but no, it does not. I've already tried your suggestions as mentioned in the question: *"Start ADB server as root - no luck"*

Comment: I had similar problem and its gonna fixed with same. without accessing as root. :). well try another port.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but as you can see this question is already solved ;) The green tick below the number of votes means the answer is accepted :)